# How to hide image alt text/caption in Visual Composer?

Tags: images, text

Every time I hover on an image in a Wordpress page made with Visual Composer it displays the alt text or caption when i remove the alt text when uploading an image.

For SEO reasons I would like to use the alt text, but I don't want it to be visible on the front end when hovering.

Is there any way to disable this with a short code in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

i had also the same issue when using the AVADA theme. It appends the title attribute on the image which is showing the text/caption when its being on hover.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* The first line waits until the page has finished to load and is ready to manipulate */
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* remove the 'title' attribute of all <img /> tags */
    $("img").removeAttr("title");
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried adding that code to custom css setting but didn't work. Also tried adding it to additional javascript, but still shows the alt tags.